# Redirect area to default Url mvc 5 ef 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

i use EntityFrameWork 6 and MVC 5.
i have 2 area : user and admin areas;
user area Works well , but when i go to admin area (each pages in admin area) redirect to default url (default url has in User area).
when tracing each request from admin area take me this message:

> Response Code : 302

I have no idea why this happens
[image]

RouteConfig :

```
namespace MyWeb
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , title = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new []{"MyWeb.Controllers"}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and Area Registration:

```
 public class SuperAdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "SuperAdmin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "SuperAdmin_default",
                "SuperAdmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }


public class UserAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "User";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "User_default",
            "User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your routing class. May be you have wrong route there.

Comment: All three route seems to true

Comment: Can you please edit your question and information how you configured routing

Comment: Are you setting `area = ""` in your URL that you are building? If you don't override the area, it will remain the same as the current area because MVC reuses route values from the current request.

Comment: Update my Question and add Rout and area registration. yes i user `area=""` but for controller on the root project (not areas)

Comment: I think the problem is Authorize attribute, cuz `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` doesn't work but `[Authorize]` is work